# Bug only in IE 9 setSelection is not scrolling to the selected row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This bug is present only in IE 9.

When using `setSelection` – the target row is getting selected  as expected, but the view area is not scrolling up to the selected row. It stops one row before the selected row.

You can see it on the demonstration page from trirand.

> 1. [trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
> 2. Click to : **New in version 3.4**
> 3. Click to : **Scroll with dynamic row select**
> 4. Select the first row (or any other). Then click **Edit Link** then keeping press press **Next** all the way upto the 7th row. Note that it's working fine until there. However, after that the target row is getting selected  as expected, but the view area is not scrolling up the to selected row. It stops one row before the selected row.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be working on jqGrid site. Post your code with where you are facing the problem.

Comment: check in internet explorer its not working...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the mode you are running your browser in.. Go to compatibility view of IE9 .. It works perfectly for the scroll in that mode

Answer (score 0):

Thats true!! I was facing similar issue... Actually i selected my Browser Document Mode:IE9 standard & Browser Mode:IE9. When i changed Document Mode:IE7 i found the grid row selection to be in that exact row of i want it to be focussed.
So try changing your Browser Document Mode and also ensure your Browser Mode to be in compatibility view which will solve most of the browser issues.